# Difference in terms of security when using Hosted UI vs Amplify Pre-built UI component when using Amazon Cognito User pool as identity provider?

Tags: javascript, security, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using Amazon Cognito User Pools as Identity Provider and access management in Web Application (react) and have no plans to use Social IDP or other external IDP.

Amazon Cognito User pools will provide user details, attributes and groups. I am planning to use for the Groups for the authorisation.

If I use  Amplify Pre-built UI component does that mean it is not OAuth 2 code flow (and also means no PKCE)?

That means only hosted UI has OAuth2 PKCE support? Does that mean using hosted ui option is more secure compare to using Amplify Pre Built UI?

While, I find lot's of sample code etc but could not find this information. Appreciate if someone can point me to document or elaborate my understanding?

Comment: One thing for sure #Cognito is very poor in documentation and very much a product in progress. 

In a hindsight I would move to Auth0 or Okta and ditch Cogntio.

Comment: We have decided to ditch Cognito for Auth0